# pip freeze/list команды вызывают ошибку: locale.Error: unsupported locale setting

Tags: python, linux, pip, модули, locale

Не могу получить список установленных пакетов pip. Ввожу команду `pip freeze`

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

---

Ввожу команду `pip list`

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 215, in main
    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
locale.Error: unsupported locale setting
```

---

Как решить эту проблему?

---

Вывод команды `locale`

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Вывод команды `locale` покажите.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

И если у вас что-то дебиано-подобное, то еще нужно будет так:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Comment: Второй вариант помог. Благодарю